# svelte typescript typing in markup

Tags: typescript, apollo, svelte, svelte-3

I am using svelte with typescript. Is it possible to do typing in the markup?

```xml
<div>
  {#if $getTasks.loading}
    Loading...
  {:else if $getTasks.error}
    Oh no! {$getTasks.error.message}
  {:else if !$getTasks.data}
    No data
  {:else}
    <ul>
      {#each $getTasks.data.queryTask as task (task.id)}
        <li>
          <TaskItem
            id={task.id}
            text={task.title}
            completed={task.completed}
            on:remove={remove}
            on:toggle={toggleStatus}
          />
        </li>
      {/each}
    </ul>
  {/if}
</div>
```

`$getTasks` is set to 'any' in the `<script lang=ts>` code.

However, you can see below that VS does not know what `task` is.  I would like to set it to my `task interface`.  Any way to do this?  Obviously I use typescript for the type usage here.

[image]

Thanks
J

Comment: What does your `getTasks` look like? is it imported from a ts file?

Comment: No, Apollo: ```const getTasks = subscribe(client, { query: GET_TASKS } as any) as any;```

Comment: why do you need the `as any` at the end?

Comment: `query: GET_TASKS` will be underlined, as it is a different type... the second `as any` will underline `{#each $getTasks.data.queryTask as task (task.id)}` the `queryTask` in this code... the problem is there is no way to set the type for `task`... I need to know how it could be done...