# How to do type annotation in markup section

Tags: typescript, svelte

Not sure if it's duplicate of [svelte typescript typing in markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767614/svelte-typescript-typing-in-markup), but since that one is not answered, and my question is slightly different, I might try.

Svelte has [`await` block](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-await) that can await for a Promise and make the result available for the block. Suppose I fetch an object with type `T` from somewhere, then use `T`'s field `foo` inside the block. Since there is no way to annotate that object with type `T`, `npm check` always complains that `Error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'unknown'. (ts)`, though the code works perfectly.

If I write something like `{#await my_fetch() then my_object: T}`, the error becomes `Error: Expected } (svelte)`. It doesn't matter if `T` is correctly imported or not, because this is syntax error.

I can't find a way to annotate type outside the `<script>` block at the top of the svelte file, but the linter complains about type missing in markup section anyways. Am I missing something?

In the worst case, I can just ignore these false alarms and move on, but if there's way to clear these up please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use TypeScript syntax in the template; that is a [known limitation](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701). To my knowledge there also is no way to ignore such errors, only Svelte warnings (e.g. about accessibility).

In this specific case you can wrap `my_fetch()` in another function in the `<script>` section to type the result correctly. (`await` correctly unwraps the type of the awaited Promise, so maybe something is wrong in the original function's typing of the Promise.)

Comment: Yes! Wrapping `my_fetch()` in a annotated function (`const wrap_fetch = async (): Promise<T> => { ... }`) solved the problem. `my_fetch()` didn't work because itself is a template function from a library.

Comment: And thanks for confirming the known limitation.

Comment: I just found the issue relating to this and have linked it in my answer.